# How to handdle the errors in catch - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, try-catch

I was wondering how to handdle the errors in promise. I have registration form with email and personal code inputs. When somebody dont fill the input there is an error. But when email or personal code exist in my base I would like to redirect him to login page - because his account exist. And there is a problem. If I have an email in my base, he is redirect to login (it is ok), but when he write wrong email but good personal code I have an error in my console.
Here is a code:

```
       Promise.all(auxData).then(() => {
          this.profileCheck()
        .then(() => {
          // some code
        })
        .catch(e => {
          if ( e.email.custEmailExists == "This email existe." ) {
            co.postLogin(loginData).then(data => {
             this.$router.push({ name: "login" }); 
            });
          } else if (
            e.person_code.custPersonCodeExists == "this personal code 
               existe") {
             this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
          }
         });
    });
```

So in this second condition (this is case when email is wrong and personal code exist) my error is: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'custEmailExists' of undefined". 
This errors showing automaticaly from my api. 
The first condition is dropped, because email is new, so it has to focus to the second condition. But it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript tries to check value of `e.email.custEmailExist`, but e.email is `undefined`.
Use:

```
if (e.email && e.email.custEmailExists == "This email existe.")
```

or:

```
if ((e.email || {}).custEmailExists == "This email existe.")
```

The second one is a little bit more hacky.

Comment: Thank ypu! It is working! I knew it, it was something in my conditions :)